# Play multiple instances of an html5's Audio object

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm making a small game in Javascript and it requires some audio for better user experience.
The main issue I have is that I have to play 1 song/sound multiple times, and sometimes at the same time.
However, if I cloneNode the Audio object, the audio is downloaded one more time from the server, and so is only played latter, as it has to be downloaded first. So the sound can be downloaded over 100 times during normal game !

As I coulnd't find an answer on Internet, I'm asking you :)

Please note, that I want to do that with my own code, and not with a library.

Comment: I think it's cached.

Comment: Do you want to play 1 song multiple times or multiple songs at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Solutions using `new Audio()`/`HTMLAudioElement.play` are good for things like music, but won't allow playing multiple copies of the same audio at a time. For sound effects, the right tool to use would be an [`AudioBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer) from the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). As a simple example:

```js
const playButton = document.getElementById('play');

let interval = null;

playButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  // if already started playback, just stop it
  if (interval !== null) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
    return;
  }

  // create an audio context
  const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
  
  // fetch a sound effect, and get an ArrayBuffer
  const resp = await fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/68/Crash.ogg');
  const arrayBuffer = await resp.arrayBuffer();
  
  // decode the ArrayBuffer into an AudioBuffer
  const audioBuffer = await audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer);
  
  // set an interval for every 250ms
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    // create an AudioBufferSourceNode
    const source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
    
    // set the AudioBuffer
    source.buffer = audioBuffer;
    
    // connect it to the default sound output
    source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
    
    // start playback
    source.start();
  }, 250);
});
```

```html
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this, but it might be worth trying to use data URIs for the src of the audio clips that need to be played simultaneously. This would prevent the server hit when you clone the element - although the fact that it is downloaded each time really sounds like a browser bug. I would think it should be pulled from browser cache.

Looks like someone has tried this already: [Is it possible to use data URIs in video and audio tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270151/is-it-possible-to-use-data-uris-in-video-and-audio-tags)

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is to make a function that makes and plays an audio element, all in a function. I think it would be something like this:

```
var makePlayAudio = function(src) {
var aud = new Audio();
aud.src = src;
aud.play();
}
```

Then, you can call it whenever you want.

Note: I have only tested it in Chrome.

Comment: This won't work on mobile browsers because there is no caching.

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend doing is separating the parts of the program where the audio downloads and where it plays. It sounds like cloneNode() does both, so don't use that.

Try loading the audio file once at the start of the code, like this:

```
const music = new Audio("filename.wav");
//(or whatever file extension the audio is)
```

Then, whenever you need to play its audio, use .play() on the variable representing your file.

```
music.play();
```

You can also play it in a function if you want to specify other details about how it plays, to save space.

```
function playMusic(audioFile,loop=false,playbackRate=1) {
    //This line plays the audio file
    audioFile.play();
    //This line sets whether the audio will loop (false by default)
    audioFile.loop=loop;
    //This line sets the playback rate (speed basically)
    audioFile.playbackRate=playbackRate
}

//Calling the function to play music normally
playMusic(music);
//Calling the function to play music with special, optional parameters set
playMusic(music,true,2);
```

With .play(), you should be able to play the audio file whenever you want, without loading it again. With a function like the example above, you can also set attributes easily for each individual call. All without loading the same file constantly.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to cloneNode the audio object. Just call play() on the same object from JavaScript and it will play each time the function is called. If it is already playing, it will restart. See https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox#Controlling_media_playback

Comment: The poster wants multiple instances of the same sound playing simultaneously.

Comment: So, use cloneNode().play().

Comment: @Triang3l how performant is that? Maybe there's a better way using WebAudio APIs