# Preloading audio + gif with html5 and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a splash page that autostarts a wav file in correlation with a gif.  What I'd like to do is display a loading wheel until both the wav file and gif are completely loaded so they play in sync.  I would have rather used an swf, but the client does not have the original project files so I'm stuck using a crappy gif that loads very slowly, and the wav file will only start to play once the page has completely loaded.  I need them both to play at the same time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Interesting enough! Its almost a 2-part question. First you need to detect when both two are loaded but the tricky part (without knowing much detail from a commenters end) is to detect if the gif FPS matches the audio framerate. If it does, all it requires is to match them up properly.

Comment: Thanks, apparently you can extract frames in Photoshop thank god.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `XMLHttpRequest` and `data uri` to load both gif and audio file. Track `onreadystatechange` event on both. When both completes, you can set `httpRequest.responseText` directly into their `src` attribute. For example following code can be executed after html load completes..

```
var imageData = "";
var audioData = "";

function onHtmlLoad()
{
    // Show loading wheel..        

    var isImageLoaded = false;
    var isAudioLoaded = false;    

    var imageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.website.com/path/to/image.gif', true);

    imageRequest.onreadystatechange = function(e) {  

        if(imageRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(imageRequest.status == 200)
            {
                isImageLoaded = true;
                imageData = imageRequest.responseText; // data uri..
                if(isAudioLoaded)
                    loadSplashScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    imageRequest.send();

    var audioRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    request.open('GET', 'http://www.website.com/path/to/audio.wav', true);

    audioRequest.onreadystatechange = function(e) {  

        if(audioRequest.readyState == 4)
        {
            if(audioRequest.status == 200)
            {
                isAudioLoaded = true;
                audioData = audioRequest.responseText; // data uri..
                if(isImageLoaded )
                    loadSplashScreen();
            }
        }
    }

    audioRequest.send();
}

function loadSplashScreen()
{
    var imgEl = document.getElementById("myImgElement");
    var audioEl = document.getElementById("myAudioElement");

    // loads immediately..
    imgEl.src = imageData;
    audioEl.src = audioData;

    // Hide loading wheel..
}
```

But also mind that size of `data uri` you will set in `src` attribute can be limiting, [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270151/is-it-possible-to-use-data-uris-in-video-and-audio-tags).
Hope this helps..