# Capture loaded source of audio tag, using Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to save the currently-loaded source file of an audio tag. Sounds simple, but here's the catch: the source gives a random sound file on every request.

The audio tag is created, the source set, and the audio played with JavaScript, as seen here:

```
function createAudio() {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');

    audio.setAttribute('id', 'file_audio')
    audio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
    audio.setAttribute('autoplay', 'true');
    audio.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
    audio.appendChild(createSource());
    return audio;
}

function createSource() {
    var source = document.createElement('source');
    var d = new Date();
    source.setAttribute('id', 'file_audio_source')
    source.setAttribute('src', 'file.wav?r=' + d.getTime());
    source.setAttribute('type', 'audio/wav');
    return source;
}

this.switchAudio = function() {
    var d = new Date();
    $svjq("#file_audio").find('audio').remove();
    $svjq("#file_audio").find('source').remove();
    $svjq("#file_audio").find('embed').remove();
    if (Modernizr.audio.wav) {
        document.getElementById("file_audio").appendChild(createAudio());
    } else {
        $svjq("#file_audio").append('<embed id="file_audio_embed" name="file_audio_embed" src="file.wav?r=' + d.getTime() + '" autostart="true" cache="false" type="audio/wav" hidden="true" loop="false" enablejavascript="true">');
    }

};

this.playAgain = function() {
    if (Modernizr.audio.wav) {
        document.getElementById('file_audio').play();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('file_audio_embed').play();
    }
};
```

I need be able to save the currently-loaded file in the source. However, if you access the file URL in the browser it returns a different file.

Automated processes such as Watir-WebDriver, Capybara (Capybara-Webkit), and Mechanize also return a random file. For example:

```
require 'capybara'
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit('url')
session.click_link 'play sound' #on every click u get a new sound
session.click_link 'play again'

#file_audio_source
e = session.find_by_id('file_audio_source')
e[:src]

#save the current open page and opens it
#session.save_and_open_page

#returns different file
session.visit(e[:src])

#returns different file
session.execute_script("window.open('"+e[:src]+"')")

require 'Mechanize' 
agent = Mechanize.new{|agent| agent.ssl_version, agent.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}

filedata = agent.get(e[:src]).content
aFile = File.new("/Users/me/Documents/test/test111.wav", 'wb')
#aFile.syswrite(filedata)
```

Could the file be embedded into the HTML or cached? And is there a way to get the file and save it locally?

Other options include recording from the sound device or using the mic to record the sound played, though this option is not at all ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

opt.1:

```
require 'capybara'
session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
session.visit('url')
session.click_link 'Play sound'#this gets the file into the cache, then use the codes to get in out
```

opt.2

```
#execute the javascript that loads the file/creates the sound url. no playing of the sound
session.execute_script("document.getElementById('file_audio').appendChild(createSource());")
e = session.find_by_id("file_audio_source")
session.visit(e[:src])
```

Watir and Capybara perform great ! :)
but now the problem is to make it headless
and it seems that the headless browser doesnt act the same and the non-headless ??

> A method to give headless functionality

```
def headless_get_file url
  require 'uri'
  res = @session.driver.cookies
  agent = Mechanize.new {|agent| agent.ssl_version, agent.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE}

  uri = URI('https://....')
  res.keys.each do |i|
    temp = res[i]        
    cookie = Mechanize::Cookie.new(i, temp.value)
    cookie.domain = temp.domain
    cookie.path = temp.path
    agent.cookie_jar.add(uri,cookie)        
  end

  filedata = agent.get(url).content
  aFile = File.new("#{dir}/file.wav", 'wb')
  aFile.syswrite(filedata)
end
```

> Could the file be embedded into the html or cached?

yes it can ! [Is it possible to use data URIs in video and audio tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270151/is-it-possible-to-use-data-uris-in-video-and-audio-tags)

```
<audio controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="data:audio/wav;base64,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" />
</audio>
```

> is there a way to get it and save it locally?

yes u can !
you just have to find the cache directory :)

http://www.digitalmediaminute.com/article/626/viewing-browser-cache-in-firefox

and then right a little code to go and fetch it this codes goes with opt.1 not opt.2

```
def getlatestdir(newdirs)
times = Array.new
newdirs.each_with_index do |newdir,index|
  times[index] = File::mtime(newdir)
end
temp = times[0]
count = 0
times.each_with_index do |time,index|
  if temp < time
    temp = time
    count = index
  end
end
return newdirs[count] 
end

def getCacheDir
#how to get the path
#in irb enter
#require 'capybara'
#session = Capybara::Session.new(:selenium)
#session.visit('https://www.google.co.za')
#--- then open a new tab and enter about:cache
#copy the disk cache device cache directory ( from /var/... to .../T/ )
path = '/var/folders/9x/51cvmc215xx6zy9vd_64sxwc0000gn/T/'
dirs = Dir.glob(path +'*/')
newdirs = Array.new
dirs.each_with_index do |dir,index|
  if(dir.include? 'webdriver-profile')
    newdirs[newdirs.length] = dir
  end
end
the_cache_dir = getlatestdir(newdirs) + 'Cache'
return the_cache_dir
end

def saveFile
rifffile = ''
count = 0
the_cache_dir = getCacheDir
files = Dir.glob(the_cache_dir + '/*/*/*')
files.each_with_index do |file,index|
  bytes = open(file, 'rb'){|io|io.read}
  str = bytes[0].to_s + bytes[1].to_s + bytes[2].to_s + bytes[3].to_s
  if(str == 'RIFF')
    count = index
    rifffile = file
    break
  end
end
puts rifffile
filename = 'test123.wav'
#read file bytes
bytes = File.open(rifffile, 'rb'){|io|io.read}
#write file to the directory
f = File.new(filename, 'wb')
f.syswrite(bytes)
return filename
end
```

granted the above code isnt the greatest or fastest, but it gets the job done

> Other options include recording from the sound device, or using the mic to record the   sound played

thats would take too long and too much effort :P

In summary, opt.1 is ok but not great, opt.2 is far, far better :)

ajt

Comment: with getting it headless its all about the session cookies