# Javascript make audio blob

Tags: javascript, html, audio, blob

I am testing the html audio tag and I would like to **make audio blob url's**, like youtube or vimeo does, and add it to the **"src"** to start playing the audio.

I've been testing with `new Blob()` and `URL.createObjectURL()` but I don't know how to use it.

I would like to do something like:
`<audio controls src"blob:null/8142a612-29ad-4220-af08-9a31c55ed078"></audio>`

I would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Suppose you have base64 encoded version of audio like this

```
data="data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAADSeWyXAU9nZ1MAAAAAAAAAAAAA0nl";
```

1.First remove the base64 headers (preamble) and decode it to pure binary form, the form it lies in as in your iPad. You can use [convertDataURIToBinary](https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746) an excellent snippet by [borismus](https://github.com/borismus) on github for that

```
var binary= convertDataURIToBinary(data);
```

2.Now create a Blob from the binary; specifying the type of audio it is

```
var blob=new Blob([binary], {type : 'audio/ogg'});
```

3.Now create blob url out of this Blob

```
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

That's all now simply replace `src` attribute of `<source>` to this blob url.In case you already have the pure decoded binary then you just do step 3

https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/uubnnr0w/

Comment: Worked perfectly for me in Summer 2022 using Vue3.0 and Laravel inertia. Many thanks!