# How to get Blob data from an existing audio element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, binary, blob

I know the location of the `mp3` file in my server. I have loaded it into my View and the `<audio>` element can play it. Now I want to extract the loaded blob data from the `<audio>` element. I found examples on web, but these only show how to upload a file using an `<input>` element.

I want to know how to get the binary data from an existing `<audio>` element like this:

```
<audio id="myAudio" src="/Media/UserData/mp3DataFolder/5f67889a-0860-4a33-b91b-9448b614298d.mp3"></audio>
```

Thanks from now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326823/javascript-make-audio-blob/40329529

Comment: Thanks , but I dont have any `base64` data in this link. do you know how can I convert this `mp3` file to `base64` with javascript ?

Comment: What do you want to do with this Blob?

Answer (score 9):

You can simply fetch this url and set the responseType of your request to `"blob"`.

```js
var aud = document.getElementById('aud');
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', aud.src);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = e => console.log(xhr.response);
xhr.send();
```

```html
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3" id="aud" controls>
```

Or using the fetch API:

```js
var aud = document.getElementById('aud');
fetch(aud.src)
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(console.log);
```

```html
<audio src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1cdwpm3gca9mlo0/kick.mp3" id="aud" controls>
```

Of course this assumes that the server holding your audio file allows you to fetch it from client (which it should in your case since you shown relative urls).

Answer (score 1):

Hi you could first convert it to base 64 then blob:

key method:

```
var bufferToBase64 = function (buffer) {
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    var len = buffer.byteLength;
    var binary = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    return window.btoa(binary);
};
```

[ https://codepen.io/xewl/pen/NjyRJx ]

Then follow this answer to create the blob.

[Javascript make audio blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326823/javascript-make-audio-blob/40329529)

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sanddune/uubnnr0w/

Comment: thanks for trying to help me, but just need to read this data from my audio element which is alreadyi have got an exist path for source.