# How do I read metadata properties from MP3 file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mp3

I know questions similar to this have been asked before, specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332384/read-id3-tags-from-mp3-using-javascript), but all the answers usually involve one of two things, both of which I'd like to avoid:

1. Importing a new library, or,
2. Using FileReader, which as far as I can tell, only works for user-inputted files.

I'm making a little game that includes the option to switch between several music tracks in the options menu, and I'd like to be able to show the track title and artist. I could adjust my song object so that I input information like title, artist, etc. into the code, but it just seems simpler to include that as metadata on the file so that I only have to input the filename. Is there any way I can read metadata off of files that aren't inputted by a user without using an extra library? Here's the Song object that I'm using, although it's pretty simplistic:

```
var Song = function(filename)
{
    this.intro = new Audio(); // the introduction of the song that leads into a loop
    this.intro.src = filename + "-intro.mp3";
    var temp = this;
    this.intro.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        temp.loop.currentTime = 0;
        temp.loop.play();
    });

    this.loop = new Audio(); // the main file that will be looped. Also has the relevant metadata
    this.loop.src = filename + ".mp3";
    this.loop.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        this.currentTime = 0;
        this.play();
    });
};

var songs = [
    new Song("track1"),
    new Song("track2"),
    new Song("track3")
];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use mutag for this

In your html add:

`<script src="sanjit1.github.io/mutag/dist/mutag.min.js"></script>`

and in your js add:

`const mutag = window.mutag;`

and using the variable `filename`,

```
mutag.fetch(filename).then((tags) => {
      console.log(tags);
});
```

Comment: I tried with both the source string and the Audio object, but for both it says, "Failed to execute 'readAsArrayBuffer' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."

Comment: oh, you will have to grt the file blob ill help with that once i get home

Comment: @KRLW890 Quick question is your application a web application or a js application? ALso are you using nodejs here?

Comment: I'm not using Node.js, and I'm pretty sure it's a js application (bit of a novice so I'm not 100% sure what the difference is). But I managed to find something that worked by merging the code you provided with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52925966/how-to-get-blob-data-from-an-existing-audio-element-with-javascript):
`var getTags = function(audio)
{
    fetch(audio.src)
        .then(response => response.blob())
        .then(mutag.fetch)
        .then((tags) => { console.log(tags); });
};`