# How to parse and play Blob/Binary data from database in Angular 5

Tags: sql-server, angular, angular5, blob, html5-audio

In my Angular 5 application, I am retrieving data which is stored as `VARBINARY(MAX)` in SQL Server database. It looks like this in the database field: `0xFEA47E451A40AE4571E51F...`

When I retrieve it from database using a GET call via .NET WebAPI, it is shown like this in console from my Angular app: `aFwwbUYFjhvbv=bhBGVJHvchjhcbsHKfvHbbh...`

I know the MIME type of this data (it is either MP3 or WAV). How can I parse/read this data in Angular 5 client and play it using an HTML `<audio>` component?

I have looked at several related solutions but none seem to be applicable due to one error or another, or perhaps there is a lack of understanding on my part.

My assumptions are that Blob data has the audio content which I can play. I have to convert it to a File first. This is what I am trying:

```
const file = new File([blobData], "audio.mp3")
this.audioSource = URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

And in the HTML, I assign `audioSource` as the source of an HTML5 component.

```
<audio [src]="audioSource" type="audio/mp3"></audio>
```

This results in a `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error.

I tried `sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.audioSource)` as well but this doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the intended effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329529/1160236

if you have blob data with correct binaries all you have to do is to create URL using `URL.createObjectURL(blob)` then pass it to the audio tag as a source. (check step-3)

if you don't have blob data with correct binaries you can create blob data as shown in step-2.

I have created an [Angular example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-audio-blob) which uses `DomSanitizer` via a custom pipe.

```
<audio [src]="audioSource | safe:'url'" id="audio" controls #audioTag></audio>
```

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329529/1160236

Angular implementation using reference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-audio-blob

DomSanitizer example: https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/angular-safe-pipe-implementation-to-bypass-domsanitizer-stripping-out-content-c1bf0f1cc36b

I hope this will help. just remember all you need is valid blob data.

Comment: I figured this out not 30 minutes after starting the bounty! :D Nonetheless, thank you for the StackBlitz example, it is exactly what I ended up doing. I was missing the `atob(base64)` part only. I'll be awarding you the bounty shortly.