# convert audio source to a "use-once" blob

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I want to make it a little bit more difficult for users to directly download **MP3** files from the server (just from going straight to the `URL` of the source). I've been looking around and, from what I've gathered, a good way to go about this is to convert an `Audio` object to a use-once `Blob` (similar to how **YouTube** does it).

As an example, something like this:

```
<!-- directly accessible, unobfuscated url -->
<audio src="www.mywebsite.com/media.mp3"></audio>
```

Would become:

```
<!-- visiting the link would lead to a 'your file was not found' page
     and the original url is now obfuscated -->
<audio src="blob:http://www.mywebsite.com/6fc4f9d2-035a-4999-b330-96da04c0f6a8"></audio>
```

At the moment, this is how I'm doing it:

```
var url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/media.php"; // media.php points to an mp3 file
var audio = null; // just for simplicity sake - i'm not actually doing it like this
if(!audio){
    audio = new Audio(url);
} else {
    audio.pause();
    audio.src = url;
}
```

Now I was looking at [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40326823/javascript-make-audio-blob) answer (along with a couple others), but they all either involve using a file selected from an `input` or, as this one is, using the file as a `Base64` string and converting *that* to a `Blob`, which I can't figure out how to do and imagine to be a somewhat heavy task to do on the client-side.

Essentially, all I need to do is convert the `url` to a `Blob` that can only be used once in that session (cannot be directly accessed in another tab - just that one time it's being played, for example).

**NOTE:** I Tagged `PHP` as this may also be a server-side issue, feel free to correct that *if* necessary.

Comment: You can not "blob" an address as source. Read about [blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob).

Comment: @MarkusZeller I know, you can only blob an `object`. I’m just curious how to do that and make sure it’s only use-once :)