# how add audio in html5 with base64 encoding

Tags: html, base64, html5-audio, wav

i have a string it is audio record in base64 encoding and in wav  format(i have data link - {{vm.record}}). 
I need add audio player in widget( which had written on js + html) that play audio to me

I don't understand why it don't work ? do i must to write smth in js that this start work ? where i can write about encoding ?

```
<div layout = "row">
                    <audio 
                        controls 
                        src={{vm.record}} type="audio/wav; base64" autobuffer="autobuffer" autoplay="autoplay">
                        Your browser does not support the
                        <code>audio</code> element.
                    </audio>
                </div>
```

i know that this is wrong "type="audio/wav; base64" but how right?
i try this, but it don't work too

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAAfm5nB6slBlZ3Fcha363d5ut7u3ni1rLoPf728l3KcK"/>
```

Comment: is that angular ? src={{vm.record}} ?? Could you check the browser console ?

Comment: You say the recording is in wav format. That suggests in your second code sample, you should replace `audio/ogg` by `audio/wave`. The first code sample might be wrong because the data format prefix is missing there, but it's hard to tell without seeing the exact content behind `{{vm.record}}`.

Comment: It is byte array base64 wav  get from microphone with pyaudio -  `{{vm.record}}` = TWFuIGlzIGRpc3Rpbmd1aXNoZWQsIG5vdCBvbmx5IGJ5IGhpcyByZWFzb24sIGJ1dCAuLi4=

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can have an HTML5 `audio` tag in base64 encoding as so:

```html
<audio controls autoplay loop src="data:audio/ogg;base64,BASE64CODE" />
```

No need for a `type`! :)

Comment: ok,  but how i can write link and type of data in src at the same time ?

Comment: @Hedgehog Many file types have data URIs. They are data:audio/ogg for OGG files, data:image/png for PNG files, etc etc. You can end a data URI with base64 if you follow along with ;base64, I like to use this https://iandevlin.com/blog/2012/09/html5/html5-media-and-data-uri/ website as it explains data URIs well and has some examples too!

Answer (score 0):

If your audio files are over about 20MB then you might run into performance problems and errors in some browsers (notably Firefox). For this reason I recommend converting the Base64 into a binary Blob as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329529/1417989) using the [convertDataURIToBinary](https://gist.github.com/borismus/1032746) snippet and then setting that as the `audio.src`.